# VMware Workstation "Recording/Replaying VM activity" feature

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have seen some documentation about a "Record/Replay VM activity" feature in VMware workstation 6 and 7 here :

- http://cto.vmware.com/the-amazing-vm-recordreplay-feature-in-vmware-workstation-6/
- http://www.vmware.com/pdf/ws65_manual.pdf

But I don't find that feature in my VMWare Workstation 10. I don't find any manual for the 10th version by the way.

Do you know if that feature has been removed ? Or do you know where I can find the feature in VMware Workstation 10 (or 9) ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

This feature was [removed in VMware Workstation 8 (released September 14, 2011)](http://www.replaydebugging.com/2011/09/goodbye-replay-debugging.html).

There's http://rr-project.org/ (Linux-only), which provides low-overhead (I believe typically under 1.5x) record/replay, and gdb interface. Mozilla developers now use it to debug intermittent failures in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the video capturing function was removed from VMware Workstation 10 because there were serious problems regarding quality and the functionality overall. See for example: [Workstation 9 Movie Capture of Console screen doesn't work](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/417641).

The function removal is being discussed and was confirmed by a VMware representative in this thread: [Where is the "capture movie" menu option ?](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2303493)

Description of this function has also been removed from the product documentation.

Comment: I'm talking about the "Recording and Replaying 
Virtual Machine Activity" not about the Video capturing feature. But they have maybe removed both features at the same time. Any other idea ? :)